# Verify transaction was included in certain block within smart contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, merkle-patricia-tries

Is there a good resource for proving that a particular transaction was included in block x?

Comment: Just check the `eth.getTransactions(txHash)` on geth console and you see a non-zero block number. Or just search for your transaction on etherscan

Comment: Looking for a way to do this within a smart contract. Which as I understand only has access to block hashes.